# Can I use level triggered epoll with non-blocking socket?

Tags: sockets, networking, server, epoll

There are many examples using edge triggered epoll with non-blocking socket. But I can't find any example using level triggered epoll with non-blocking socket. I think the second one is much easier and as good as the first one. Am I right? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hei, man. Did you still need the answer?